# Access key from child component in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

According to [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Component), binding a key is required to use custom components in a v-for:

```
<template v-for="(task,i) in tasks">
    <task-card v-bind:task="task" v-bind:key="i"></task-card>
</template>
```

I would like to use that key in the child component (`task-card`), but neither using `this.key` or adding `key` as a prop (is a reserved Vue keyword) works. Is there a way of doing this without passing yet another prop with the value "i"? Currently working with `"vue": "^2.5.9"`.

Comment: `this.$vnode.key`.

Comment: I've been trying to intentionally access the value of key inside of my components that use `v-for`. I tried accessing via `this.$vnode.key` but I'm getting an error. "Cannot read property 'key' of undefined". Any ideas how to access `key`'s value? Maybe it's changed since 2017.

Comment: @Ryan Hopefully this will help someone in the future. I only received 'undefined' when I tried to access `this.$vnode.key` from a child component. If you're using a child component pass the key through `props`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you want to pass data to the child, you should be using props (`key` is reserved so you'll have to name it something else).

Otherwise you can access the key on the vnode within the component via `this.$vnode.key`.

**Vue 3**

For Vue 3 the API has changed. You will need to access the vnode from *internal private instance* like so: `this.$.vnode.key`. As far as I know this is undocumented and may change; use with caution.

Comment: I've been trying to intentionally access the value of key inside of my components that use v-for. I tried accessing via this.$vnode.key but I'm getting an error. "Cannot read property 'key' of undefined". Any ideas how to access key's value? Maybe it's changed since 2017

Comment: get TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key') too on 2021

Comment: I've edited the answer with a Vue 3 solution.

Comment: Anyone knows how to access this.$.vnode.key on <script setup> ?

Comment: I've digged into Ant Design Vue's source only to find out what exactly happened to the "lost" `key` in child component, so here is the snippet (below in the link), in which the author calls `getCurrentInstance()` to get the component instance, and access the bound `key` from `instance.vnode.key`, in this way the child component can "find back" the "lost" `key` props,

link here: https://github.com/vueComponent/ant-design-vue/blob/main/components/menu/src/MenuItem.tsx#L41-L44