# How to specify "key" as a required prop?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want this

```
export default {

  props: {
    key: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  ...    
}
```

But it leads to a runtime error:

```
[Vue warn]: "key" is a reserved attribute and cannot be used as component prop.
```

*EDIT:*

To clarify: I want the reserved attribute "key" to be required. This is because my component relies on the trick of "Forcing component recreation by key change". [(link)](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#preferred-solutions)

Comment: Can't you just prefix it, like maybe: `input-key`, `something-key`?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik: no, because I am referring to the one special attribute named "key".

Comment: As you can see in console, key is reserved attribute, so you can't use it. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access key from child component in vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783396/access-key-from-child-component-in-vue)

Answer (score 5):

`key` is one of [special attributes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Special-Attributes) reserved by Vue.js.

It can't be passed as a `prop`, same as `ref`, `slot`, `scoped-slot`, `is`.

Simply rename the `prop` to any name of your choice.

If usage of property named `key` is crucial inside child component, it is possible to create a computed property `key` inside child component that will return value from passed `prop` and will be accessible within child component.

Answer (score -2):

VUE update view because of data's key has changed. the key is special in props. so support you use other word.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JRRY.png)