# Using v-for on a custom component, can I access the value of ":key" inside of the component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, v-for

When using v-for to create a list of custom components, I often find myself binding the `item.id` to the value of my `:key` *and* `:id` props. I'm wondering if (and if so, how) I can access the value of `key`, perhaps as a prop inside of my component. This would effectively save me the hassle of having to create an `id` prop on every component that uses a `v-for` directive.

```html
<my-component v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" :id="item.id"></my-component>
```

```js
// MyComponent.vue
props: ['key']
```

Registering `key` as a prop and using `this.key` in the app produces a value of `undefined`. So clearly I can't simply reference the `key` as a prop.

Suggestions?

Comment: Your key is the same as `item.id` which is getting passed as `id`, why not access that instead?

Comment: The idea is that I don't have to add `:id="this.id"` prop to every component where I use `v-for` and bind a `:key="item.id"`. I NEED to use a `key` with `v-for`. The key needs to be unique. You almost always end up using some form of `id` property on the object you're looping through to register your `key`. So why do I need to write basically the exact same line of code twice in every component where I use v-for? `:key="item.id" :id="item.id"` It's so redundant. I'm convinced there's a way to access the key value. Maybe there's a prop `keyValue` that vue passes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access key from child component in vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783396/access-key-from-child-component-in-vue)

Comment: @painotpi Unfortionately, no. "Cannot read property 'key' of undefined". I think it may have changed since 2017. I'm using Vue3 and I assume that must have been either a Vue or Vue2 answer.

Comment: I couldn't find much information on `v-for` changing between vue2 and vue3, and as the linked answer suggests, `key` is reserved, so the only way to get this working would be props. You could also try asking this in the `vuejs` discord channel.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for giving it a shot! I'll give Discord a try. I'm hoping I found the right one - Vue Land? I'll give it a go, there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been asking around and it looks like the value of `key` is used more for Vue's virtual DOM which makes it far less usable as a data property within the component itself. Because the virtual DOM can change, the value of `key` may change out-of-sync to the data's intended `id` property, if Vue finds it efficient to do so. This makes using it to reference the `id` of a specific object in data unreliable.

If someone else has a better explanation, please share.